# Application_BeginRequest executed twice

Tags: c#-4.0, .net-4.0, dotnetnuke, global-asax, redirect

In my `Global.asax` file i have `Application_BeginRequest` which is executed twice on each page load. My code is below:

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
if ((rawUrl.StartsWith("/article.aspx?articleid=")) || (rawUrl.StartsWith("/article.aspx?id=")))
            {
                int ArticleId = int.Parse(rawUrl.Remove(0, rawUrl.IndexOf('=') + 1));
                Entities.ArticleTemplate _temp = Common.CommonUtil.GetArticleTemplate(ArticleId);
                HttpContext.Current.Cache["ArticleTemplate"] = _temp;
                redirect301(_temp.Url);
            }
else
        {
            // Handles all HTTP redirects.
            string url = GetHTTPRedirects(rawUrl);
            if (url != string.Empty)
                redirect301(url);
            else
            {
                string new_url = GetRedirectUrl(rawUrl);
                if (new_url != String.Empty)
                {
                    redirect301(new_url);
                }
            }
        }
        return;
    }
```

I don't want the `Application_BeginRequest` to be executed twice, because then there are two calls made to the same stored procedure which increases load on Sql Server. Please help.

Comment: If you are using DNN, you typically won't be working with the Global.asax file....

Comment: @ChrisHammond Then how to handle the redirects?

Comment: Ideally you would have URL rewriting going on with the various URL providers in DNN

Comment: You would be much better off creating a handler to do this.